# Show different website layout if no sidebar added

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, widgets

I have a question about website layout with and without wp widges in sidebar. Here is the code i have for my registered sidebar.

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
|| !dynamic_sidebar(products) ) :
endif;
?>
```

And this is the code i have in functions.php

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
        $opts   = array(
        'name'          =>  'Products',
        'before_widget' =>  '<div id="%1$s2" class="container %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  =>  '</div>',
        'before_title'  =>  '<p class="h4">',
        'after_title'   =>  '</p>'
    );
    register_sidebar($opts);
}
```

I have wrote my own css for two different layouts when designing the website for my client. They are One-column layout and two-column layout which is one small & one big column layout(for wp widget purpose).

Is there any way i can display the webpage to 1-column website layout if i didn't add wp widget to the page i want? In other words, the web page will be one-column if there is no widget applied or else will be two-column website layout if that page is with widgets?

Probably this way that i'm want it to be.

```
<?php if --- with sidebar ---
?>

<div id="column-1">
Column 1 appears
</div>

<?php elseif --- without sidebar ---
?>

<div id="column-2">
Column 2 appears
</div>

endif;?>
```

Do you think this way work? Please advice.
Will be great if this can be done in wp php coding. Thank you!

Comment: You can get specific template parts via [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Comment: Hi! I wrote different codes in one single css file. I just want to use php code to make it display differently when with widget or no widget on the page. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is_active_sidebar()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_active_sidebar/) as a condition to enqueue your styles. It does precisely that — tells you if it has any widgets assigned.

PS stop `function_exists()` madness :) that is completely pointless check in modern WordPress.

Comment: Hi Rarst, i have updated my question. Would you please take a look and provide a suitable solution? Appreciate your response and Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this inside your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'dynamic_layout' );

function dynamic_layout() {
echo '<style type="text/css">'; 

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'secondary' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'main' ) ) {//If both sidebars are active
?>
#blog {

width: 100%;
}

<?php } // End If both sidebars are active 

else if ( !is_active_sidebar( 'secondary' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'main' ) ) {/*If main sidebar here*/
 ?>
.post {
width: 239px;
margin-right: 7px;
}

<?php }/*End If main sidebar here*/

else if ( !is_active_sidebar( 'secondary' ) && !is_active_sidebar( 'main' )) {/*No sidebar*/
?>

#blog {
float: none;
max-width: 100%;
}

<?php } /*End No sidebar*/

else if ( is_active_sidebar( 'secondary' ) && !is_active_sidebar( 'main' ) ){/*If only secondary sidebar is here */
?>

#blog{
float: left;
}

<?php }   /*End If only secondary sidebar is here */
echo '</style>';
}//End function dynamic_sidebar_layout
```

Comment: What if i want to do this in my html file? Because i have a few different sidebar on different pages. So that i can adjust any page i want. Thanks!